# Matrix of scatterplots by month-year

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

My data is in a dataframe of two columns: y and x. The data refers to the past few years. Dummy data is below:

```
np.random.seed(167)
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=365*3)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"y": np.cumsum([np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(365*3)]),
     "x": np.cumsum([np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(365*3)])
    }, index=rng
)
```

In first attempt, I plotted a scatterplot with Seaborn using the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_scatter(data, title, figsize):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    ax.set_title(title)
    sns.scatterplot(data=data,
                    x=data['x'],
                    y=data['y'])

plot_scatter(data=df, title='dummy title', figsize=(10,7))
```

[image]
However, I would like to generate a 4x3 matrix including 12 scatterplots, one for each month with year as hue. I thought I could create a third column in my dataframe that tells me the year and I tried the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_scatter(data, title, figsize):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    ax.set_title(title)
    sns.scatterplot(data=data,
                    x=data['x'],
                    y=data['y'],
                    hue=data.iloc[:, 2])
df['year'] = df.index.year
plot_scatter(data=df, title='dummy title', figsize=(10,7))
```

[image]
While this allows me to see the years, it still shows all the data in the same scatterplot instead of creating multiple scatterplots, one for each month, so it's not offering the level of detail I need.

I could slice the data by month and build a for loop that plots one scatterplot per month but I actually want a matrix where all the scatterplots use similar axis scales. Does anyone know an efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create multiple subplots at once, seaborn introduces [figure-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html).  The `col=` argument indicates which column of the dataframe should be used to identify the subplots. `col_wrap=` can be used to tell how many subplots go next to each other before starting an additional row.

Note that you shouldn't create a `figure`, as the function creates its own new figure.  It uses the `height=` and `aspect=` arguments to tell the size of the individual subplots.

The code below uses a [`sns.relplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) on the months.  An extra column for the months is created; it is made categorical to fix an order.

To remove the `month=` in the title, you can loop through the generated axes (a recent seaborn version is needed for `axes_dict`). With `sns.set(font_scale=...)` you can change the default sizes of all texts.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(167)
dates = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=365 * 3, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({"y": np.cumsum([np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(365 * 3)]),
                   "x": np.cumsum([np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01) for _ in range(365 * 3)])
                   }, index=dates)

df['year'] = df.index.year
month_names = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=12, freq='M').strftime('%B')
df['month'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df.index.month - 1, month_names)

sns.set(font_scale=1.7)
g = sns.relplot(kind='scatter', data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='year', col='month', col_wrap=4, height=4, aspect=1)
# optionally remove the `month=` in the title
for name, ax in g.axes_dict.items():
    ax.set_title(name)
plt.setp(g.axes, xlabel='', ylabel='')  # remove all x and y labels
g.axes[-2].set_xlabel('x', loc='left')  # set an x label at the left of the second to last subplot
g.axes[4].set_ylabel('y')  # set a y label to 5th subplot

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.06, bottom=0.06)  # set some more spacing at the left and bottom
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot using months]

Comment: Thank you! I have three follow-up questions. Is it possible to remove "month = " and only show the actual month label as the title of each scatterplot? Is it possible to show the horizontal axis title only once at the bottom and the vertical axis title only once on the left? Is it possible to change the font size relative to the size of the scatterplots?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much! If you had fours rows of charts instead of three (I have four rows of three months each using col_wrap=3), how would you set the vertical axis title at the centre of the matrix of charts? I tried different combinations using my 4th and 7th charts but couldn't really get it at the centre of the matrix of charts.

Comment: Maybe `g.axes[3].set_ylabel('y', loc='bottom')`?  Or using figure text coordinates: `g.fig.text(0.005, 0.5, 'y', rotation=90, ha='left', va='center')`?